# Java - For Loop instantly meeting requirements

Tags: java, for-loop

I'm trying to populate a deck of cards, and I've come to an odd problem. I assume it has a simple solution but I can't find it for the life of me. Any help would be appreciated.

What's basically happening is, it enters the For loop, and the initialized int is instantly the size of the final required size. Even though it is initialized at 0.

```
/* Create Deck */
String[] deck = new String[52];
int y, z, i = 0;
for (z = 0; z < 3; z++); // Loop while fills deck array
{
    for (y = 0; y < 12; y++);
    {
        deck[i] = CreateCard(y, z); //Trigger CreateCard method for each card
        System.out.println(deck[i]);
        i++;
    }
}
```

When the code enters the line `deck[i] = CreateCard(y, z);`
The values of z is 3 and y is 12. Why does this not run through the entire deck?

Comment: You have a semi-colon at the end of each loop declaration, e.g. `for (z = 0; z < 3; z++); ` - so the body of the loop is empty. Voting to close as a typo.

Comment: Note that if you'd declared `z` and `y` *within* the loop header, e.g. `for (int z = 0; z < 3; z++)`, you'd have noticed this because they wouldn't be in scope in the `CreateCard` call (which should be `createCard` to follow Java naming conventions, btw).

Comment: I had tried declaring them inside the loop but I didn't understand the error message I was getting :P And thanks for the the naming conventions reminder, I'm still getting my head around it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have semi column at the end of the for loop declaration. And you know when we have a semi column at the end of the loop, the body of the loop does not runs with each iteration and when the condition of for loop terminates then the body of the loop executes only once.

**Corrected Code**

```
    /* Create Deck */
String[] deck = new String[52];
int y, z, i = 0;
for (z = 0; z < 3; z++) // Loop while fills deck array
{
    for (y = 0; y < 12; y++)
    {
        deck[i] = CreateCard(y, z); //Trigger CreateCard method for each card
        System.out.println(deck[i]);
        i++;
    }
}
```